# Workflow rule creation through managed package

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, winter23

We have workflow rules in our managed package, As salesforce is stopping the support for creation of new workflow rules after Winter ’23 release, Will it still allow the creation of workflow rules through managed package installation ? If Yes till when this will be allowed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_mgmt_block_workflow_rules.htm&type=5&release=240), You can able to create workflows using managed packages.

> The next step toward retiring Workflow Rules is to disable the
> creation of workflow rules. You can still activate, deactivate, and
> edit any existing workflow rules. And you can still create automations
> in Flow. To test and create workflow rules for use in managed
> packages, developer orgs still allow you to create workflow rules.
>
> Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce
> Classic in Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and
> Unlimited editions.
>
> Why: Most workflow builder use cases are now supported in and work
> better in Flow. We understand that migrating your workflow rules may
> take some time, but creating more workflow rules potentially creates
> more migration work later on. Use the Migrate to Flow tool to make the
> move. For edge cases that the Migrate to Flow tool doesn’t support,
> refer to Equivalent Features in Flows and Workflow Rules for tips on
> manual migration.

Comment: Thanks @Ankaiah Bandi for the reply. Still trying to understand the below statement "To test and create workflow rules for use in managed packages, developer orgs still allow you to create workflow rules." I understood that workflow rules creation is allowed in developer orgs, did it says it allowed via managed packages in any edition ?

Comment: Its only developer edition. You cannot create managed packages from a sandbox. Generally, sandbox organization is configured to create unmanaged packages only. Unmanaged packages are not upgradeable. You need to signup for Developer Edition to create a managed package